# How can I lower z-index of iPad3 MP4 player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad

I just noticed strange iPad3 (iOS 5.1) issue that I understand but I don't know how to fix.

**Short version:** IPad's player covers all my divs. How can I make it display below them?

**Long version:** I've got vimeo video embedded on website. On top of that vimeo video I've got two containers that cover 25% of the left side of Vimeo video and 25% of the right side.

When user clicks on left container he goes to previous video, if users clicks right container he goes to right video. Those are big 25% wide arrows and the middle part of Vimeo video can be clicked for "PLAY" functionality (50% of width in the middle is not covered so he can click).

It works very good!

BUT... when I play that video on iPad 3 it becomes MP4 player or something and COVERS both containers (they are not clickable - video takes full 100% width and covers my arrows). **How can I lower z-index of iPad3 MP4 player? Or do something else to have my arrows still on top of it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read somewhere that setting a css transform with no real effects can "hack" this into fixing the z-index bugs, so why not try (I dont have an ipad to try this on with me today):

-wekbit-transform: translate(0, 0);

in the CSS for the video.

sorry if its no good, if i can find the original source ill post it

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work. Too bad that it even covers "Firebug for iPad" so I can't do any code checks.

Comment: Shame :), I found the blog deep in the bookmarks, maybe theres something else http://blog.millermedeiros.com/html5-video-issues-on-the-ipad-and-how-to-solve-them/

Comment: I've found a way! Imagine: main container is 100% wide, video is 80% wide inside, arrows are 25% wide on sides BUT they are partially outside video. This gives 10% of left and 10% of right free space to touch them. It worked :) Some creative solution to this problem but it's okay with me! Thanks!